# Can anyone use SolGSN: Solana Gas Station?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, rust, rustc

I want to use SolGSN, where the user can't pay the gas fee like transferring the NFT. The admin has to pay the fee. However, this repository is outdated, and I've encountered several errors due to version changes. Are there any other APIs or SDKs available that can help us achieve this?
I have also reviewed the approach for gasless transactions, but it's different from what I want to implement. The logic I intend to apply is that the user sends the SPL, but the transaction fee is covered by the admin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a few ways to do this. One is using [`Octane`](https://github.com/solana-labs/octane) which is a gasless relayer developed by Solana Labs. Another is coding this together yourself. Each transaction has a `feepayer` field, so if you set this to a different admin keypair the user will not be charged for fees. More on how to do this in [this question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2901/set-feepayer-for-sol-transaction).